# Does using `lazy-seq` recursively take up stack frames?

Tags: recursion, clojure, lazy-sequences

I'm learning about lazy seqs at the moment, and I've noticed that they usually involve recursion without using `recur`. For example, here is the implementation of `iterate`:

```
(defn iterate
  "Returns a lazy sequence of x, (f x), (f (f x)) etc. f must be free of side-effects"
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [f x] (cons x (lazy-seq (iterate f (f x)))))
```

I was under the impression that if you recurse without using `recur`, it will make a new stack frame for every call, which can cause stack overflows if you iterate enough times.

Does `lazy-seq` gobble up stack frames? If not, how does it avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lazy-seq` is not actually recursing when you see it include a call to iterate in this example. Rather when you request the second item the lazy-seq macro unrolls itself into a suspended call. So each time you retrieve an item you are causing one more invocation, but the old call is not on the stack.

Also of interest is whether you are consuming memory, and that depends on what you do with the head of the sequence. If you retain in a var or local binding, the entire chain of cons cells will be held. If you avoid holding the head, and traverse down the sequence, GC can clean up behind you.

One tricky bit is that the lazy-seq macro has some special meta in it ^{:once true} that lets the compiler know that the fn closure is a single-time thing and not to hold onto any closed over variables.

Answer (score 1):

No lazy-seq doesn't gobble up stack frames.

On the face of this code it may seems like a recursive call BUT lazy-seq is not a function it is a macro which in this particular case will translate to:

`(lazy-seq (iterate f (f x))`

becomes something like

`(new clojure.lang.LazySeq (fn [] (iterate f (f x))))`

As you can see that the iterate function call is wrapped inside another function (that what makes it lazy, i.e the function will be called later).